# How to solve the absolute value inequality $9|x + 9| + 6 > 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1.) A phrase that describes a set of real numbers is given. Express the phrase as an inequality involving an absolute value.
All real numbers x at least 8 units from 2

$$|x-2|\geq8$$

Is this correct?

2.) Solve the absolute value inequality. Express the answer using interval notation. 
$$9|x + 9| + 6 > 5$$
Can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: 1. is good. Please show your attempt at 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to the first question correct. For the second one, we have
\begin{align}
9|x+9| + 6 > 5 & \iff 9|x+9| + 6 - 6 > 5 - 6 \\ 
& \iff 9|x+9|  > -1 \\
& \iff \frac{1}{9} \times 9|x+9|  > \frac{1}{9} \times -1 \\
& \iff |x+9|  > \frac{-1}{9}
\end{align}
But the absolute value is never negative, and thus, in fact all real numbers satisfy the inequality $9|x+9| + 6 > 5$. The solution set is thus $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ℝ meaning "all real numbers" or in interval notation: (-∞,∞)?

Comment: @Jimmie Yes. $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The first is ok.

The second like this:

$9\hspace{1 mm}\big|x+9\big|+6>5$

$\Longrightarrow 9\hspace{1 mm}\big|x+9\big|>-1$

$\Longrightarrow \big|x+9\big|>-\dfrac{1}{9}$

$\therefore x\in\mathbb{R}$